# Use datagrams in java to send video/audio from client to server?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

Hey everyone, I'm having a bit of a problem with UDP and Datagrams.  I'm supposed to make a server that will get a request from the client to send a file in the same directory.  The UDP Server will then get this file (a video), put it into a datagram and send it.  I think I know how to do it, but I can't put the file in the datagram. I'm putting it in Binary form, so keep that in mind.

Here's my code so far:
edit: This is the server by the way, and I keep having trouble with BufferedInputReader and OutputReader, so keep that in mind :)

```
   Scanner inFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);
    int port = 12345;
    DatagramSocket server = new DatagramSocket(port);
  // Read name of file supplied by client (must be a line of text):
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    DatagramSocket request = server.accept();


    // Create buffer, then we're ready to go:
    // Puts file into binary form
        BufferedInputStream inbinary = 
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("poop.txt"));
   // Outputs the binary form
        BufferedOutputStream outbinary = 
                new BufferedOutputStream(request.getOutputStream());

    int numbytes;
    int countblocks = 0;
    int countbytes = 0;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, port);
    server.receive(packet);

    while ((numbytes = inbinary.read(buf,0,1024)) >= 0)
    {
     // receive packet from client, telling it to send the video file
     server.receive(packet);
     InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
     packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
     server.send(packet);
     countblocks++;          // keep statistics on file size
     countbytes += numbytes;
     outbinary.write(buf,0,numbytes); // write buffer to socket
    }
      outbinary.flush(); // FLUSH THE BUFFER
      server.close(); // done with the socket
      System.out.println(countblocks + " were read; " + countbytes + " bytes");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done datagrams in a while, but I'm pretty sure the `accept()` call is wrong. That's for TCP servers.

I'd recommend cribbing from Sun's excellent tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Comment: Oh yeah I know, I meant to remove that, woops!